# Are quasi-affine varieties Euclidean dense?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about algebraic geometry. Please excuse the many mistakes that will be in this question.

Consider the complex Euclidean space $\mathbb{C}^n$. As far as I understand, an algebraic set can be defined as the set of common zeros of finitely many complex polynomials in $n$ indeterminants. If I read the definition correctly, then the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the topology whose closed sets are algebraic sets. Since affine varieties are connected (in the Zariski topology) algebraic sets, if I am not mistaken, nonempty Zariski open subsets, which are open subsets with respect to the Zariski relative topology, of affine varieties are dense with respect to the Zariski topology.

My question is, whether a nonempty Zariski open subset of an affine variety $\mathbb{V}$ is dense with respect to the Euclidean topology.

If we consider the whole space $\mathbb{V} = \mathbb{C}^n$, then this holds true since proper Zariski closed sets are Lebesgue nullsets. If $\mathbb{V}$ was an analytic submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then the assertion would hold true since it holds true under charts. Unfortunately, not each affine variety is a submanifold, e.g. the coordinate cross $\{(z_1,z_2)\,\big\vert\,z_1 = 0~\vee~z_2 = 0\}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ cannot be flattened in zero, unless I made an error.

I am very much certain that this question is well-answered already, but I have yet to find the correct source. Most of the books I consulted did unfortunately not consider the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Hopefully, somebody can give a hint towards the answer to this question. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not entirely awake at the moment, but I think that "Unfortunately, not each affine variety is a submanifold" can be fixed. Have you considered that the singular locus of an affine variety is a proper Zariski closed set? Or in other words has measure $0$ within that variety. Or in yet *other* words, there is a dense open subset of $\mathbb V$ that **is** a manifold. Can you fix your argument using this fact?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I already considered that the nonsingular points of a variety are an analytic submanifold. Unfortunately, this does not help unless I am thinking it the wrong way. The submanifold that you mention is a Zariski open subset, that is therefore Zariski dense. If I could prove that it was also Euclidean dense, then I would be essentially done. Maybe this is easier to show, but unfortunately I can't think of a way. Could you please elaborate what you mean with "measure $0$"? Can we equip varieties easily with a measure compatible with the Euclidean topology?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, Tabes Bridges, for your suggestion, which ultimately led me to the right path. The answer to my question seems to be yes.

In the 1977 edition of Shafarevichs "Basic algebraic geometry" he proves on page 319 the Lemma 1:

> If $X$ is an irreducible algebraic variety and $Y$ a proper subvariety, then the set $X(\mathbb{C})\setminus Y(\mathbb{C})$ is everywhere dense in $X(\mathbb{C})$.

I am a bit embarrassed to not have found this earlier.

Additionally, I stumbled upon this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222174/density-for-the-non-singular-points-in-real-varieties) where some examples of real algebraic varieties whose singular points are not Euclidean dense are given.